# How to solve Pybluez OSerror

Tags: python, bluetooth

I would like to connect a Lego Mindstorms NXT using pybleuz to my labtop.
But when I search for the Mindstorms I get the following error:

```
import bluetooth

print("performing inquiry...")

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(
        duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False)

print("found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices))

for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    try:
        print("  %s - %s" % (addr, name))
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("  %s - %s" % (addr, name.encode('utf-8', 'replace')))
```

I get the error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-bcb3970d611c> in <module>()
      4 
      5 nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(
----> 6         duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False)
      7 
      8 print("found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.pyc in discover_devices(duration, flush_cache, lookup_names, lookup_class, device_id)
     24                       lookup_class=False, device_id=-1):
     25     if device_id == -1:
---> 26         device_id = _bt.hci_get_route()
     27 
     28     sock = _gethcisock (device_id)

OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

​

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: downvoted for inserting screenshots - hard to read and no copy/paste possible

Comment: @ack Have a look now please

Comment: did you mix python version 2.x and 3.x?

Comment: @ack I thought that I was using python 2.x all the time... how do you come to that conclusion ?

Comment: print "this is python 2.x" vs. print("this is python 3.x")

Comment: @ack in which line do you see such a mix ?

Comment: @ack  BTW: I just changed the notebook kernel to python 3 and I still get the same issue.